# ImageMagick not working within docker environment

Tags: c#, docker, service, .net-core, imagemagick

I am using .Net Core. In one of the service application, I am using ImageMagick. Nuget package Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU 7.14.3. When I run this service locally on windows, the below mention last log statement returns count as 1, which is correct, while when I run the same service under docker, then the last log statement returns 0. I think I am missing some setting that needs to be done for the docker environment. Can someone suggest?

```
public ImageModel CreatePDFPreview(Stream stream)
{
    _logger.Information("Creating PDF preview for stream of size {size}", stream.Length);

    var settings = new MagickReadSettings();
    settings.Density = new Density(300, 300);

    using (var images = new MagickImageCollection())
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        images.Read(stream, settings);

       _logger.Information("Images created for the stream, total {count}", images.Count);
    }
}
```

When I am running the service in docker, I am not getting any exception, just that `images.Count` is returned as `0`.

As suggested in one of the posts, I added this in my project file, bit no luck.

```
<ItemGroup>    
    <PackageReference Include="Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU" Version="7.14.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 4):

Any chance you're missing [GhostScript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) in a docker environment and have it in local environment?
This tool is requirement for Magick.Net to convert PDFs to images.
Check [Convert PDF docs](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/docs/ConvertPDF.md) for more info.
If I understand, you're reading PDF stream and trying to convert it into an image?

Also, please check comment about Ghostscript on [Magick.Net github](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/tree/master/docs).
Make sure to match platform of your Magick.NET (32 or 64 bit). There is also an option to set path to Ghostscript directory if only dlls are copied over like:
`MagickNET.SetGhostscriptDirectory(@"C:\MyProgram\Ghostscript");`
There is also warning about license which is required if Ghsotscript is intended for commercial use.

Answer (score 3):

I was daces a same issue with `Magick.Net` deployed in docker. @Nesaje assumption about about missing `GhostScript` library helped me to find solution. I added ghostscript in `Dockerfile` with command:

> RUN apt update -y && apt install -y ghostscript

Comment: ghostscript is installed in docker now, but somehow MagickNET is not working. did you used `MagickNET.SetGhostscriptDirectory` ?